# unable to structure optimal query

Tags: sql-server, database, relational-database

I have been struggling with best possible solution for a requirement. 
While adding a feature for a product, I have to check in database the following:

If feature with Category "A" is being added, then check if Category "B" exists in the database for the product. If it exists and has either of the 2 status "Status1"/"Status2" then raise an error depending upon the status.

I have to hard code for 3-4 categories being added for e.g. 
If cat1 is being added then check if there cat2 exists for this product, if it exists then check the status (status has to be either 'status1' or 'status2'). If it's status1 then raise different error than status2.

Please help.

Thanks